# Chrome browser window size has stopped showing

Tags: google-chrome

Until recently when I have the dev-tools open in Chrome, a little window-size display would appear in the top-corner of the window.  This has now stopped appearing. Has anyone else experienced this or know how to get it back?

I have a feeling that Chrome may have updated recently as I know notice a .cls button in the styles tab when using the element inspector.  Am now on Version 49.0.2623.87 m   (I have seen there was an update on the 8th March)

Thanks

Comment: I know that there is now the "toggle device mode setting" which is cool

Comment: Am guessing that the new device mode (icon top left of dev tools) negates the need for it and is pretty cool. Am leaving the question here though in case anyone else asks.